# The Great Tagging Reorg and tag-based badges

Tags: discussion, tags, badges

How will [the great tagging re-organisation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg) (10k MSO rep required) affect you if you are working towards a specific tag-based badge, if at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you retag a answer you've got upvotes for, those votes will affect the new tag(s). Same goes for a reorg.